# Time complexity of recursion inside of for loop

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Can you help me with the time complexity of this bit of code. I think it's 3^n but I'm a newbie so I'm probably wrong.

```
public void find(int n) throws Exception
    {
        if (n == vertices){
            throw new Exception("Solution found");
        }

        for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++)
        {
            if (control(n, r))
            {

                color[n] = r;
                find(n + 1);

                color[n] = 0;
            }
        }    
    }

    public boolean control(int n, int r)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
            if (graph[n][i] == 1 && r == color[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I guess I misunderstood some things and the complexity is n.

Comment: Is this homework or some kind of assignment? Why do you think it is `O(3^n)`?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing `control` and `find` methods.

Comment: If you're doing a function that is `O(n)` 3 times, that's not `3^n` - it's `O(n)` still.

Comment: Howerver, interesting way to tell "Solution found.".

Comment: I couldn't really find another working way to exit the method so I used exceptions. Which is probably very wrong and not what it's intended for.

Comment: @lexicore sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @LutzHorn yes, it is an assignment. I tried to solve it with the master theorem and I found 3^n -1 / 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on this

**EDIT:** This applies when the base condition does not throw an exception

1. `control` method has a loop that runs for `vertices` number of times - So it is `O(vertices)`.
2. `find` is a recursive function that stops when `n` reaches `vertices`. (Assuming `n` starts from 1) It calls `control` for n=1,2,3... vertices.

`find` is called from a loop for 3 times. Each recursive calls involves this and hence this makes it exponential - `O(3^vertices)`.

So, finally, it is `O(3^vertices)` * `O(vertices)` which is `O(3^vertices)`

**EDIT:**

Since you have `throw new Exception("Solution found");`, it will blow up once `n` reaches vertices. So it is `O(vertices^2)` in that way.

Comment: I've been thinking about this and I'm curious. Does the fact that the thrown exception is caught change its complexity? Or do exceptions stop it from going any further in any case and it's O(vertices^2) no matter what. Sorry, I had to ask.

Comment: If you catch the exception and ignore (or not throw exception) the recursion continues for other values of `r` (`2,3`).

Comment: Ohh. My code catches the exception which I should've probably shown. Sorry.

Comment: No. Having a catch outside `find` will not have any impact. It will still be O(vertices^2).

Answer (score 0):

```
       n
      /|\
     / | \ 
    /  |  \
   /   |   \
(n+1) (n+1)(n+1) --> control(vertex)-> O(Vertex)
 /|\
/ | \ . . . .   . .
```

So it seems there are total, `3^1+ 3^2+...+3^vertex` nodes and on each node you are doing `O(n)` operation on each node. So the complexity is `O((3^1+ 3^2+...+3^n) * n)` = `O((1-3^n)/2)*n)` eventually `O((3^vertices)*vertices)`.

Comment: @lexicore What I told is partially correct, there is an exponential component as the recursive call happens in a loop

Comment: @user7 I don't see why. `find` calls `control` at most 3 times and `find` recursively at most once. Won't that be `vertices*(3*vertices)` i.e. `O(vertices^2)`?

Comment: @lexicore How are you saying `find` recurs at most once. Once it hit the base condition did you consider `r=2,3` (assuming base condition won't throw an exception as in the OP ;))

Comment: @lexicore So, I missed the `throw Exception` part. So you considered that? In that case `find calls control at most 3 times ` is not right. As the loop runs at most once in each recursive call

Comment: @user7 You are right. I was wrong. If `graph[n][i]` is always `0`, it will recur 3x.

Comment: @user7 Interestingly at the end I was both right and wrong. Right that it will effectively not branch because when recursive invocation reaches `find(vertices)`, it will stop. Wrong because it will not branch for different reasons than I initially thought.